# Return undefined value in jQuery ajax call with promise

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried many times with jQuery ajax call but it return value before updating it. i have googled it and tried lots of solutions no one work for me, i always get undefined value because function return value before ajax call complete. any help would be appreciate,

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(secondvalidation());
});

function onemorevalid() {
  console.log("working");
  //this ajax call return 1
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'handler/email.php',
    method: 'POST',
  });

}


function secondvalidation() {
  onemorevalid1 = new onemorevalid();
  onemorevalid1.done(function(data) {
    console.log("data " + data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

output on console is

```
working
undefined
data 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making an object out of a method. Which is wrong fundamentally. Also if you need to pass the value of an ajax call to code called afterwards, you can add `async:false` to you query so that the code will wait for the ajax response.

Just make sure that you call the `other_function()` after the ajax method gets called in document ready function.

So I think what you need is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var requested_data;


        var request = $.ajax({
      url:'handler/email.php',
          method:'POST',
          async:false,
          dataType: 'text'
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
       console.log("data " + data);
 requested_data = data
    });



 function other_function(){
console.log("toing_toing: " + requested_data);
}
other_function();  
   });
```

here's a [working example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grbwssz4/) of this code.

Please note that there are other ways to achieve this as [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516912/jquery-continue-another-ajax-function-after-the-first-ajax-function-call-is-full). `async:false` may cause your script to freeze till the request is complete, and thus if the request took a long time that would give a bad UI experience.

Comment: How i can use this returned data in another function

Comment: Thanks @toing_toing,  your answer useful but as you are using "async:false"; it is deprecated, can we do something like your answer  without using "async:false";

Comment: @Ganesh you should have a look at the linked answer. There are many other ways mentioned in that.