# MVC Select Option Value Assign

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, select-options

I am new to Web development, and here is my problem.

I have 2 functions inside my JS file.

1. GetTransactionCodeList
2. GetSelectedTransactionCodeFromDB

Both functions are called inside $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
GetTransactionCodeList();
GetSelectedTransactionCodeFromDB();})
```

The application should fill up the $('#Select') Option List completely in GetTransactionCodeList() before the value from GetSelectedTransactionCodeFromDB() is assigned to $('#Select').

But, what I am facing right now is the GetSelectedTransactionCodeFromDB() is start to assign the value to $('#Select') before the Option is completely fill-up.

Do anyone of you know what is happening here?
I have tried to use something like function().Then(Function2()) (sorry I have forgotten what is this called already) method in JS but it doesn't help in this scenario.

Appreciate your advice.

** This project is on MVC Web Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways:

Call func2 on success of func1

```
function func1() {
$.ajax({ ... }).done(func2);
}
```

Use Deferred API to call func2 when funky completes:

```
e.preventDefault();
$.when(func1).then(func2);
```

Make func1 synchronous (not recommended):

```
function func1() {
   $.ajax({url: '', async: false});
}
```

ref : [Jquery continue another ajax function after the first ajax function call is fully complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516912/jquery-continue-another-ajax-function-after-the-first-ajax-function-call-is-full)